# Offline Event In Android Using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Hi, I created app in which i get data from some server i want to that if internet is not    connected then user will not able to use app. I put

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){ onDeviseReady(); }, false);

function onDeviseReady()
{
     document.addEventListener("offline", offLine, false);
}
function offLine()
{
     navigator.notification.alert(
     'No Internet Connected',message,'Message','Done');
}
```

Now what i should do in `function message(){}` so that the user not be able to move here until user connected to the internet
i put in alert box in message function but this is not i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PREFACE**

Your `app` needs Internet Connection to run, so you should check either the `device` is connected to the `internet` or not. For that you can create a `utility` function (say `hasConnection`) which returns `boolean true` on internet connection or `boolean false` on no internet connection.

**The `hasConnection` Function**

```
function hasConnection() {

var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

if(networkState === Connection.NONE) {
  return false;
}

return true;

}
```

And depending on the `hasConnction` return value you can take the right decision.

**SAMPLE EXAMPLE**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){

if(!hasConnection()){ //there is no internet connection

  navigator.notification.alert(
      'No Internet Connection!',  // message
      function(){
        /*
          If you are using jQuery mobile for UI you can create a seperate page #no-connection-page and display that page :
          $.mobile.changePage('#no-connection-page',{'chageHash':false});
        */
      },                           // callback
      'Connection Required',       // title
      'OK'                         // buttonName
  );

  return false;

} else {

//There is internet Connection, get the data from server and display it to the end user
//Again, If you are using jQuery mobile, display the page that should be displayed only when Internet Connection is available
//$.mobile.changePage('#has-connection-page');
}


/*
If the device is connected to the internet while your app is running,
you can add a listener for 'online' event and take some action. For example :
 */

document.addEventListener('online', function(){
  //Now the device has internet connection
  //You can display the '#has-connection-page' :
  //$.mobile.changePage('#has-connection-page');
});

//You can use the listener for 'offline' event to track the app if the connection has gone while the app is running.
}
```

**ONE NOTE**

Make sure that you have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in android Manifest.

**AT LAST**

I am also creating `android app` using `Phonepage` / `Cordova` and `jQuery-mobile` that needs internet connection and using this approach, working fine for me. I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for reply i already done that and that was also like this just little changes obce again thanks for your reply and i accepted it as answer because its working correctly :) thanks